# Fatal error setActiveMenu()

Tags: magento-1.9

Someone can help me? I am with an problem and I don't make idea how to fix this.

This is the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method TestAfr_AfrGrid_Adminhtml_AfrGridController::setActiveMenu() in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\local\TestAfr\AfrGrid\controllers\Adminhtml\AfrGridController.php on line 7

What I do?

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TesteAfr_AfrGrid>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </TesteAfr_AfrGrid>
    </modules>

<frontend>
    <routers>
      <afrgrid>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>TestAfr_AfrGrid</module>
            <frontName>Grid Teste</frontName>
          </args>
      </afrgrid>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <afrgrid>
              <file>afrgrid.xml</file>
            </afrgrid>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>

    <global>
        <helpers>
            <afrgrid>
                <class>TestAfr_AfrGrid_Helper</class>
            </afrgrid>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <afrgrid>
                <class>TestAfr_AfrGrid_Block</class>
            </afrgrid>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <afmodel>
                <class>TestAfr_AfrGrid_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>afrgrid_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </afmodel>
            <afmodel_mysql4>
                <class>TestAfr_AfrGrid_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>        
                    <texample>
                        <table>texample</table>
                    </texample>
                </entities>
            </afmodel_mysql4>
        </models>

        <resources>
            <testafr_afrgrid_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>TestAfr_AfrGrid</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </testafr_afrgrid_setup>
            <testafr_afrgrid_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </testafr_afrgrid_write>
            <testafr_afrgrid_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </testafr_afrgrid_read>
        </resources>
    </global>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <afrgrid>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>TestAfr_AfrGrid</module>
                    <frontName>admin_afrgrid</frontName>
                </args>
            </afrgrid>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <!-- menu config -->
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <afrgrid module="afrgrid">
                <title>Andressa</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <afrgrid module="afrgrid">
                        <title>Meu menu</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>admin_afrgrid/adminhtml_afrgrid</action>
                    </afrgrid>
                </children>
            </afrgrid>
        </menu>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <afrgrid>
                    <file>aconf.xml</file>
                </afrgrid>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**AfrGridController.php**

```
class TestAfr_AfrGrid_Adminhtml_AfrGridController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()->setActiveMenu("afrgrid/afrgrid")->addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Alguma Coisa"), Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Alguma coisa"));
        return $this;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->_title($this->__("Title"));
        $this->_title($this->__("something"));

        $this->_initAction();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

**IndexController.php**

```
class TestAfr_AfrGrid_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function IndexAction() {

        $this->loadLayout();   
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Oi"));
        $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs");
        $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("home", array(
            "label" => $this->__("Pagina Inicial"),
            "title" => $this->__("Pagina inicial"),
            "link"  => Mage::getBaseUrl()
        ));

        $breadcrumbs->addCrumb("dummy", array(
            "label" => $this->__("ai"),
            "title" => $this->__("eee")
        ));

        $this->renderLayout(); 

    }
```

Comment: What you are trying to do ? Please post code of your module

Comment: I'm trying to create a Grid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you have to change below code from

```
$this->loadLayout()->setActiveMenu("afrgrid/afrgrid")->addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Alguma Coisa"), Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Alguma coisa"));
```

To

```
$this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu("afrgrid/afrgrid")->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Alguma Coisa"), Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Alguma coisa"));
```

Use `_setActiveMenu()` instead of `setActiveMenu()` and same for `addBreadcrumb()` use `_addBreadcrumb()`

Comment: Right! That's solved the error. Thank you! 
But the grid hasn't appeared yet.

Comment: is it giving any error again?

Comment: No! Whitout errors.  The space where a Grid should appear is empty.

Comment: May be issue with grid code or collection, you can compare your code with [this blog](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/)